# wstool Source path failure

Tags: ros, catkin, wstool

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to set up a workspace i use the code
mkdir -p ~/catkin/src
cd ~/catkin/src
wstool init ~/catkin/src /opt/ros/groovy

the error I get is that
Using initial elements from: /opt/ros/groovy
ERROR in config: wstool does not allow elements without vcs information. {'other': {'local-name': '/opt/ros/groovy'}}

any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59474/wstool-source-path-failure/) by [Guru666](https://answers.ros.org/users/4545/guru666/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guru666](https://answers.ros.org/users/4545/guru666/) on 2013-03-29**:
I was following the install ROSARIA instalation for groovy but I would get an error which I cannot recall and so I was trying to correct the updated tutorial but it has since updated again and now I'm running into new problems. But thanks for the help. I was just trying to understand the wstool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not how you use wstool, can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to just create a catkin workspace for your packages, or are you trying to build ROS from source, or are you following a particular tutorial?

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0